# how to parse inner level json objects if the keys are unknown in groovy

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, automation

i am doing an automation script in which i m getting inner levels json and the keys are unknown to me so how can we parse the json so that it convert the json into a map with key value pairs it contains the json array as well as json object i want to create them separately so that we can distinguish b/w these.

i m having a json format as-:

```
{  
   "seatbid":[  
      {  
         "bid":[  
            {  
               "id":"1",
               "impid":"1",
               "price":3.5999999046325684,
               "nurl":"abc.com",
               "adomain":[  
                  "zagg.com",
                  "zagg.com"
               ],
               "iurl":"abc.com",
               "crid":"30364.s320x50m",
               "h":0,
               "w":0
            }
         ],
         "group":0
      }
   ],
   "cur":"USD",
   "nbr":0
}
```

my code is as follows but its not working at all because the key values i have to enter to get the values -:

```
 def respSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
 def respJson = respSlurper.parseText(content)
 log.info(respJson.keySet())
 log.info(respJson.values())
 log.info(respJson.get("seatbid"))`
```

Comment: This question is so unclear..

Comment: could you please explain how this is a major difference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072556/how-to-convert-json-into-key-value-pair-completely-using-groovy

Comment: simple i want the json in a key value pair

Comment: [id:1,impid:1,price:3.5,nur1:abc....] like this...

Comment: So this is the same question as this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072556/how-to-convert-json-into-key-value-pair-completely-using-groovy

Comment: but i didn't get the ans...???